# Mixing dissonance and alliteration?

Tags: technique, flow

Are alliteration and [dissonance](http://literarydevices.net/dissonance) considered mutually exclusive? My understanding is that alliteration means repetition of consonant sounds to make text flow more harmoniously, while dissonance means a combination of words that disrupts harmony. But what about a phrase like "Sweetly, slimily, and softly"?

To me, this seems both alliterative and dissonant, and I can't quite put my finger on what effect this has. Am I misunderstanding something about the concepts of alliteration and dissonance? Or is there another term for this kind of literary device?

Comment: Whatever you call it, I'm completely skeeving it, so the dissonant part certainly works! :)

Comment: Actually, it would appear, based on answers so far, that the question comes down to which textbook or dictionary you choose to look up "alliteration" in. So then you have to ask, if a passage achieves the effect that you desire, how much does it matter which academic terms are used to describe it. Remember, all these terms are descriptive, not prescriptive, and the world often turns out to be more complex than our descriptive categories can comprehend.

Comment: I had to look up "skeeve" (found it) and dissonance (didn't find it).  I understand dissonance in music, and cognitive dissonance -- but I doubt that's what you meant.  You said dissonance disrupts harmony.  What does that mean, though?  Can you provide a link and/or a couple of examples?

Comment: https://literarydevices.net/dissonance/

Comment: Thank you.  Tip: make sure the person you're responding to sees your response by including "@" and the username.

Comment: @MarkBaker The correct answer is not a question of textbook definitions. You can *hear* that "swee... sli... so..." (with three different onset clusters and three different vowels [long /i/, diphtong /ai/, and short /o/ ]) doesn't sound as smooth as "sto... sti... sto...".

Comment: I think the basic confusion you are having is the idea that alliteration makes for a harmonious flow.  Alliteration can be fun, but it isn't necessarily harmonious.  By assuming it is, you end up with what seems like a contradiction.  Instead, try to think of them as separate qualities, for example, taste and texture are separate variables.

Comment: @aparente001 Of course an alliteration is harmonious! That's the whole point of having the same sound. Same sound = harmony. And the more harmonious the alliterating words are (including similar second sounds, similar number of syllables, etc.) the better the alliteration works.

Comment: @what - So is the conclusion that alliteration and dissonance are mutually exclusive?  I will try to write something alliterative but dissonant, let's see how it comes out: *faulty, fumbling flashpoint.*  I got the first letters to repeat, but the whole result isn't mellifluous because of all the consonants (ha ha) in "flashpoint."

Comment: @aparente001 Yes and no. You can have dissonance on the level of meaning (slimy vs soft) but not on the level of sound. And of course you can have different levels of alliteration, that is, words alliterate more or less. "Faulty fumbling fool" works better than "flashpoint" (to my ear).

Comment: @what - Do you mean it's possible to have dissonance on the level of meaning without there being dissonance also in the sounds of the words?  So a dissonance on the level of meaning could also be called a contradiction?

Answer (score 4):

First, an alliteration is not a repetition of consonants, as Jason Baker has written, nor is it the repetition of the same letter or sound at the beginning of consecutive words, as Mark Baker has written, but **an alliteration is the repetition of the same sound (not letter) at the beginning of the stressed stem syllables of words (consecutive or not)**.

For example, "**s**ilken **s**ad un**c**ertain" (three /s/) in Edgar Allen Poe's *The Raven* is an alliteration, despite the "c" being a different letter and not at the beginning of the word, and "I have **st**ood **st**ill and **st**opped the sound of feet" (three /st/) in Robert Frost's *Acquainted with the Night* is an alliteration as well, despite the non-alliterating "and".

The example by Robert Frost also shows that to say that an alliteration is the first *sound* in the stressed stem syllable is not quite correct, because it is the **onset** of that syllable. The onset is the first consonant **or group of consonants** (an onset cluster). (If the syllable starts with a vowel that is a "null onset".)

And that explains part of the dissonance in your example. "**Sw**eetly **sl**imily**, and **so**ftly" is not an alliteration, or not a pure alliteration.

The other part of the dissonance comes from "slimily" having three syllables and breaking the rhythm of the sequence. "Sweetly, softly, and slimily" flows a bit better, maybe, but the alliteration is still broken and incomplete.

Comment: I disagree with your argument that "Sweetly slimily, and softly" is not an alliteration. The sound [s] can be made arbitrarily long (as opposed to sounds like [k] which are hard to extend), so it's easy to separate the 's' from the 'w' and 'l' if you insist even just a little on those [s] sounds. "Ssweetly, sslimily and ssoftly".

Answer (score 2):

Alliteration is the repetition of the same letter or sound at the beginning of consecutive words. It is not limited to consonants, and there is nothing in the definition that speaks to its purpose or effect. So, there is no conflict between the terms. You can be both alliterative and dissonant if you want to.